# Reporting Services, how to query a webservice with complex type parameter as input

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, parameter-passing, complextype

I need to query a webservice passing complex parameters in Reporting Services as input.
How can I do this?

In Query Designer at Visual Studio, I'm doing the query like this :

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>http://mywebservice.com/Customers/GetCustomers</SoapAction>
<Method Name="GetCustomers" Namespace="http://mywebservice.com/Customers/">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="myParams" type="xml">
   <DefaultValue>
        <myParams>
           <IdCustomer>0</IdCustomer>
        </myParams>
    </DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

WebService expect it as parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCustomer xmlns="http://mywebservice.com/Customers/">
      <myParams>
        <IdCustomer>int</IdCustomer>
        <IdCustomer>int</IdCustomer>
      </myParams>
    </GetCustomer>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I try it at Visual Studio 2008, I get this error message :

> Failed to execute web request for the specified URL. Soap Fault:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the xml being sent in a test client in order to get an example of the syntax needed for your query.  I recommend using the [wcftestclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364) that comes with Visual Studio.  Once you run a test, you can view the xml on the XML tab (at the bottom of the screen in wcftestclient), and replace what is in the <DefaultValue> section of your query with the corresponding parameter values.

The query for that webservice should look something like the following. Note the **a** namespace which will be depend on your own situation:

```
<Query>
  <SoapAction>http://mywebservice.com/Customers/GetCustomers</SoapAction>
  <Method Name="GetCustomer" Namespace="http://mywebservice.com/Customers/">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="myParams" type="xml">
        <DefaultValue xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebServices">
          <a:IdCustomer>0</a:IdCustomer>
          <a:IdCustomer>1</a:IdCustomer>
        </DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
  </Method>
</Query>
```

Also, I do see that you have <Parameter type="xml">. For Me, I spent hours working through a similar query and was missing the **type="xml"**.  That attribute does not seem to be well documented on MSDN.